# VPN split dns does not work on Android Emulator [Cisco AnyConnect]

Tags: android, dns, android-emulator, vpn, cisco

After connecting to a clients corporate VPN via Cisco we can access domains previously not found.
This works on Desktop, Android, iOS, iOS Simulator but **not** on Android Emulator.

We have tried to both connect the local machine to the VPN and restart the emulator and to download the Cisco AnyConnect app on the emulator itself and run it from there.
None of them work.

Our Development and acceptance environments hare hidden behind the clients VPN so we need to be able to access them from the emulator while developing.

Has anyone successfully been able to resolve split dns addresses through a VPN on an android emulator?

Answer (score 1):

After installing the Cisco AnyConnect app you have to go to
`Settings -> Network -> Private DNS`
and set it to `off`.

Now when you connect to Cisco it will resolve the split dns!

Comment: Works with FortiClient VPN app too.